# Should sentiment analysis training data be evenly distributed?

Tags: nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

If I am training a sentiment classifier off of a tagged dataset where most documents are negative, say ~95%, should the classifier be trained with the same distribution of negative comments? If not, what would be other options to "normalize" the data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what type of classifier you have but in general you don't have to normalize the distribution of the training set. However, usually the more data the better but you should always do blind tests to prevent over-fitting.

In your case you will have a strong classifier for negative comments and unless you have a very large sample size, a weaker positive classifier. If your sample size is large enough it won't really matter since you hit a point where you might start over-fitting your negative data anyway.

In short, it's impossible to say for sure without knowing the actual algorithm and the size of the data sets and the diversity within the dataset.

Your best bet is to carve off something like 10% of your training data (randomly) and just see how the classifier performs after being trained on the 90% subset.

Comment: So the core question is really "which classifier algorithms are suitable for strongly schewed data, in the 95% / 5% range?". Could you address this aspect in your answer? At least among the algorithms offered by the nltk (Naive Bayes, Maximum entropy, perceptron, etc.)